# How to prevent special character in solr search

Tags: solr

Currently I have developed the solr search in my project. Searching is work. But when I put some speical characters like ([ ] white space), I got exceptions.

```
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'searchable:       ([])': Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 13.
 Was expecting one of:
 <RANGEIN_QUOTED> ...
 <RANGEIN_GOOP> ...

at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:211)
at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParserPlugin.java:79)
at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:143)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:105)
... 104 more
```

So, how shall I handle that kind of condition. How can I prevent special characters in searcing box.

Answer (score 8):

There are some characters which Solr/Lucene uses for some operation e.g. + - ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? :
You would need to escape the special characters with backslash. Check [Escape Special Characters](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters)

Comment: I implemented to secape the special characters by using ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(q). But exception is still occuring.

Comment: I have fixed my problem with ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(q). But there is one situration for white spaces. When I put the 1 or more whitespaces, solr parsing exception is occuring. So, How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem for solr special characters by implementing ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(q). And for white spaces, I implemented q.trim(); Now my problem is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(..)](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/trunk/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.java#L196). If you need to wrap special words in addition, use

```
private static String regexp = "(^|\\s)(AND|OR|TO|NOT)($|\\s)";
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);

public static String wrap(String string) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while(matcher.find()) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        if(matcher.start() > 0) {
            result.append(" ");
        }
        result.append("\"");
        result.append(matcher.group(2));
        result.append("\"");
        if(matcher.end() < string.length()) {
            result.append(" ");
        }
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(result.toString()));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with searches specifically on the searchterms

- && (double AND characters)
- || (double pipe characters)

So I'm removing them before sending the search to solr.